# How do I change logarithmic scaled data to linear scaled data?

Tags: anova, spss, data-transformation, logarithm

I am using decibels for my research, and I was told by someone that I cannot perform any statistical analyses on these measurements other than basic descriptive statistics because the data are logarithmic scale instead of linear scale. In my searches I mostly find articles about converting linear data to logarithmic data.

How can I change my logarithmic data in to linear data so I can perform an ANOVA? I am using SPSS. Thank you!

Comment: (+1) In order to be consistent, the same "someone" would have to insist that chemists cannot do any statistical analysis with pH (also a log scale); that geologists cannot do analyses on the Richter scale (also a log scale); that financiers cannot do analyses with instantaneous interest rates (a log scale, actually); that photometrists cannot analyze light levels (guess what kind of scale?); and the list goes on and on. If this seems ridiculous and counterproductive, that's because it is.

Comment: @whuber This is a valid point; +1. To look at it from the opposite perspective, isn't every real number just the logarithm of some positive number? On what basis might one claim that a linear scale is somehow natural, rather than a historical or cultural artifact?

Comment: @user777 As you know, I am certainly not making any such claim! Even when data do have a natural scale (counts come to mind, and angles up to a positive factor), a radically pragmatic philosophy of statistical analysis asserts we are *still* free to identify and apply any appropriate re-expression of the values that can lead to insight. Having said that, we should still take care concerning what the data values mean in any application. For computing cumulative lifetime absorbed sound in an animal, for instance, we would need to estimate the actual sound levels and not their logarithms.

Comment: @whuber I believe I've expressed myself somewhat poorly. We are in vigorous agreement, I think.

Comment: To convert dB to Pascals (linear) use P=log10(value_in_dB/10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, don't transform out of the decibel scale, or at least do the analysis in both scales so that you can see if this person is foolish in insisting on the transformation.

Classic ANOVA is based on analyzing data in a scale where the magnitudes of error terms are independent of the values of the variables, and standard tests are most easily interpreted if the error terms have a normal distribution. In acoustic work you typically expect such independence between error magnitudes and variable values when you analyze data in the decibel scale, not in the scale of the underlying root-mean-square (RMS) sound pressure.

As others have noted, there is no prohibition against ANOVA on data in a log scale. If this person insists on a back tranformation to a linear scale, do the analysis in both scales and examine the residuals in your ANOVA. They will almost certainly be better behaved in the decibel scale, with the assumptions for interpretation of ANOVA significance tests met much better in the decibel scale.

To transform back to RMS sound pressure from the decibel scale (which would be most consistent with the intent of the person who is trying to talk you out of the decibel scale), you need to take into account the reference sound pressure used for defining the scale. Abstracting from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure), the sound-pressure level or acoustic pressure level $L_p$ in decibels is related to the root-mean-square sound pressure $p$ by:

> $$L_p =20 \log_{10}\!\left(\frac{p}{p_0}\right)\!,$$

where $p_0$ is a reference sound pressure, usually (but not necessarily) $20 \mu Pa$. So to get the root-mean-square sound pressure $p$ from the sound-pressure level $L_p$ in decibels, you use:

> $$p = p_0 10^{L_P/20}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Setting aside the false premise of your colleague's critique, which whuber and I discuss in the comments, the answer to your question is very straightforward: Exponentiation is the inverse of the logarithm function. If your data on the $\log_a$ scale are $x$, then on the linear scale they are $y$ such that $y=a^x$ for $a>0$.

Comment: This is a good answer--but decibels (and many other logarithmic scales used in science) are related to base $10$, so a more general formula would be appropriate.  In fact, the logarithmic base of the decibel is $10^{1/10}\approx 1.2589$.

Comment: @whuber Good point. Revised.